# how to view .class files in a rt.jar file in jdk1.6 software

Tags: java

I am looking for a `.class` file present in the `rt.jar` file, but I failed to do it.

I am ready with my Dj decompiler to view the source codes. Please tell me how to open that rt.jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Since .jar files are actually just ZIP files with another extension you can open the rt.jar file with an archive manager such as 7-Zip, extract the class file of interest and open it with a Java Decompiler. I suggest [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).